# Get all childen from cte view

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I want to get all the grandchildren,
The following logic works for me, but as this is a view I cannot pass argument xxx

SQL code:

```
WITH grandchildren as
(
    SELECT e1.ID ID, e1.LName + ', '+e1.FName FullName, 0 as lvl
    FROM lstEmp e1
    WHERE e1.ID ='xxx'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT e2.ID, e2.LName + ', '+e2.FName, lvl+1
    FROM lstEmp e2  
    INNER JOIN grandchildren g ON e2.Supervisor = g.LsuID
)
SELECT *
FROM grandchildren
ORDER BY lvl, ID;
```

I need to get this output with a `where` condition, possible?

Comment: Do you need a procedure? You can also select from the view.

Comment: I do not need a procedure, I need a way to fetch all the children from a select query

Comment: What is g. And how does e2 relate to e1? Is e2 the grandchildren of e1 xxx?

Comment: Instead of using recursive CTEs add a `hierarchyid` field to your table. The query will be a lot cleaner and faster. You could write eg: `SELECT e1.ID ID, e1.LName + ', '+e1.FName FullName, 0 as lvl
    FROM lstEmp e1 where hierField.IsDescendantOf(@root)` where `@root` is the `hierarchyid` value of the employee with ID `xxx`

Comment: To get grandchildren only you could write `SELECT e1.ID ID, e1.LName + ', '+e1.FName FullName, 0 as lvl
    FROM lstEmp e1 where hierField.IsDescendantOf(@root) and hierField.GetLevel() = 2`. To get everything down to grandchildern you could change that to `hierField.GetLevel() <= 2`

Answer (score 0):

Insert a `where` inside `grandchildren` or below `from`, this should work.

```
WITH grandchildren as
(
    SELECT e1.ID ID, e1.LName + ', '+e1.FName FullName, 0 as lvl
    FROM lstEmp e1
    WHERE e1.ID ='xxx'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT e2.ID, e2.LName + ', '+e2.FName, lvl+1
    FROM lstEmp e2  
    WHERE e2.LName = 'nameToFilter'
    INNER JOIN grandchildren g ON e2.Supervisor = g.LsuID
)
SELECT *
FROM grandchildren
ORDER BY lvl, ID;
```

Comment: I cannot have `where` condition inside grandchildren as this is inside a `view`